# Perl: See how long it takes to download file

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a perl script that tests a bunch of mirror servers for the best mirror to use.

What is the best method to see how long it takes to download a file? I am trying to avoid system calls like

```
  $starttime = time();
  $res = `wget -o/dev/null SITE.com/file.txt`;
  $endtime = time();
  $elapsed = $endtime - $starttime;
```

I'd rather use Perl functions

Comment: Why do it in Perl?  Why not use the shell and `time wget -o/dev/null SITE.com/file.txt`?  Do you plan to use `wget` (and `system`) anyway?  Or do you want to rewrite `wget` in Perl and then time that?  If the latter, then you need to search http://search.cpan.org/ to find suitable module(s) to do the job.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Portability. Not everyone has `<insert shell program here>` nor the same version of it. For example, neither OS X nor Windows come with wget. It's easier to manage dependencies on Perl modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple) or [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) (which is built in since 5.14.0).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;  # for say()

use HTTP::Tiny;
use Time::HiRes qw(time); # to measure less than a second
use URI;

my $url = URI->new(shift);
# Add the HTTP scheme if the URL is schemeless.
$url = URI->new("http://$url") unless $url->scheme;

my $start = time;
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($url);
my $total = time - $start;

if( $response->{success} ) {
    say "It took $total seconds to fetch $url";
    say "The content was @{[ length $response->{content} ]} bytes";
}
else {
    say "Fetching $url failed: $response->{status} $response->{reason}";
}
```